# What is the meaning of 'zu' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> Im Winter trage ich zu meinem schwarzen Rock auch eine schwarze
>   Jacke.

What is the meaning of *zu* here? Why is *Rock* dative while *Jacke* is accusative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also asked about the cases.

This is your sentence structure:

[PP: **Im Winter**] [V: **trage**] [NP: **ich**] [PP: **zu meinem schwarzen Rock**] **auch** [NP: **eine schwarze Jacke**].

*Rock* must be dative because it is part of a prepositional phrase with *zu*, and the preposition *zu* demands dative. Zu **wem** trage ich die Jacke? Zu meinem Rock.

*Jacke* must be accusative because it is the direct object of the verb *tragen*. **Wen oder was** trage ich? Ich trage die Jacke.

Answer (score 9):

*Zu* in this context means that you are combining *Rock* and *Jacke*. There is an emphasis that you picked the *Rock* first and then added *Jacke* to match a certain style. It is often used when it comes to fashion accessory but also when adding e.g. a certain wine to a meal.

Other examples:

- „Zu ihrem Kleid trägt sie eine rote Halskette.“ (shorter: „Zum Kleid
  trägt sie eine rote Halskette.“)
- „Zu dem Fischgericht servieren wir Weißwein.“

Comment: I like that you point out the emphasis on order...